# django incrementing div location

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a site where the client is looking to implement a "gimmic", the short version being the page will be very wide and not very long.

What I'm having trouble with is as follows:
given a list of objects, I'd like to place them to the right indefinitely.

I've currently worked out (simplified):

```
{%  for x in list %}
    <div style="position:absolute; left:{% widthratio forloop.counter0 1 400 %}">
        <img src="{{ x.image.url }}" alt="{{ x.title }}"/>
    </div>
{%  endfor %}
```

I believe this is quite a hack and am looking for a better way to implement. The greatest goal is that no matter the size of the browser the items stay in line and a scroll bar allows navigation to the right.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`display:table-cell`

http://jsfiddle.net/seler/pedhx/

Comment: Thanks for the simple solution!

Comment: @Valchris i suggest u use [this](http://code.google.com/p/html5shim/) to force IE behave like a web browser

Comment: Care to elaborate or link to where I can find more documentation on this tool?

Comment: Alternatively, replace your divs with tds in a table. Cross-browser.

Answer (score -1):

This is a CSS question, not a Django one.

In any case, the way to get things to line up next to each other is to float them.

```
<div style="float:left;">
    <img...>
</div>
```

Actually, you should have the style in a stylesheet somewhere and give the div a class which references that style.

Comment: I removed the style sheet and used the style tag for simplicity. I've tried float but if the items exceed the browser length they were starting a new row, was I missing something else?

Comment: No you are correct. Floating will not achieve what you want in this scenario (an increasingly wide page). Floats will always wrap to fit the width of their container.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using absolute positioning, you don't have to worry about the element being constrained by size, so long as you give it the style `display: inline;`. By doing so, it will grow relative to the size of the elements inside of it. You should use `display: inline;` and/or `float: left;` to ensure that your inner elements don't break onto the next line.

Comment: The only thing worse than not reading the question before you answer is posting the same answer as someone else. Dude wants an ever-widening page. Floats and inlines **won't** work because they'll always just wrap at the limits of the browser window.